# i want to print only consonant from my user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

Display user input in which odd number letter will be upper case and the letter will also display consonants from the uppercase using class method

i have tried till the uppercase conversion but the result needs to be shown in consonants

```
c = input("Enter: ")
word = list(c)
for i, x in enumerate(word):
   if i % 2:
       word[i] = x.upper()
print("".join(word))
for i in word:
    if i.isupper():
        print(i,end='')
```

result looks lie

> Enter : i am a hacker
>   I A A K R(using the uppercase method)
>   KR(only printing the consonants)

Comment: `enumerate` includes white spaces into its count. Is it desired?

Comment: only letters are included in the last step

Comment: If you are supposed to be using a class method, you should define a class.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want consonants and not vowels, there is just a small fix:

```
vowel_list = ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']
for i in word:
    if i.isupper():
        if i not in vowel_list:
            print(i,end='')
```

Comment: Many of those are not vowels. The vowels of English are `['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']` where `'y'` is sometimes included depending on context.

Comment: Sorry, my bad :`D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
c = input("Enter: ")
word = list(c)
vowels = ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']

upper = []
consonants = []

for i in range(0, len(word), 2):
    if word[i].isalpha():
        upper.append(word[i].upper())
        if word[i].upper() not in vowels:
            consonants.append(word[i].upper())

print(' '.join(upper))
print(' '.join(consonants))
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ?

```
user_input = "Some sample input to check"

word_list = user_input.split(" ")

vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

for position, word in enumerate(word_list):
    if position % 2 == 0:
        word = word.upper()
        print("Word ",word)
        for letter in word:
            if letter.lower() not in vowels:
                print("Upper Case Consonant ",letter.upper())

Word  SOME
Upper Case Consonant  S
Upper Case Consonant  M
Word  INPUT
Upper Case Consonant  N
Upper Case Consonant  P
Upper Case Consonant  T
Word  CHECK
Upper Case Consonant  C
Upper Case Consonant  H
Upper Case Consonant  C
Upper Case Consonant  K
```